# Calculate %CV for 2 pandas dataframes (or just standard deviation and mean)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, standard-deviation

I have two pandas dataframes that are the same length and width. I want to find the %CV between each cell of the two dataframes (or the standard dev and mean, and then I can calculate CV by hand).

For example, if I have something like this:

```
   A B C
0  1 2 3
1  4 5 6 
2  7 8 9
```

and

```
   A B C
0  3 2 1
1  6 5 4
2  9 8 7
```

I want to return one dataframe containing the standard deviation/mean/CV between A1 in the first dataframe and A1 in the second dataframe.

Example (mean):

```
   A B C
0  2 2 2 
1  5 5 5 
2  8 8 8
```

I want the same for standard deviation and then to calculate %CV via standard deviation / mean.

I have tried converting the dataframes to numpy

```
stan_dev = np.dstack((arr1.to_numpy(), arr2.to_numpy())).std(axis=2)
```

but I get this error:

```
TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type float which has no callable sqrt method
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with either `pandas` or `numpy`. However, I am cautious about what you hope to infer based on the standard deviation/coefficient of variation based on 2 data points.

With that warning out of the way, you'll note that the 2 answers below have a similar structure-

1. Combine datasets into a common container
2. Perform aggregation computations
3. Operate on those aggregations to calculate coefficient of variation

### NumPy approach

- `stack` to combine datasets
- aggregate with `axis=0` allows to aggregate across the lowest dimension
- calculate coef. of variation
- reassemble results into a `DataFrame`

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

arr = np.stack((df1, df2))
cv_arr = arr.std(axis=0, ddof=1) / arr.mean(axis=0)
out = pd.DataFrame(data=cv_arr, columns=df1.columns, index=df1.index)

print(out)
          A    B         C
0  0.707107  0.0  0.707107
1  0.282843  0.0  0.282843
2  0.176777  0.0  0.176777
```

### Pure pandas approach

- `pd.concat` to combine datasets and specify the `keys` paramter to obtain use a `MultiIndex` to represent data higher than 2d
- groupby to operate across the groups
- `.swaplevels` to better leverage index alignment
- use `.pipe` to calculate coef of variation

```py
import pandas as pd

out = (
    pd.concat([df1, df2], keys=[0, 1])
    .groupby(level=1)
    .agg(['mean', 'std'])
    .swaplevel(axis=1)
    .pipe(lambda df_: df_['std'] / df_['mean'])
)

print(out)
          A    B         C
0  0.707107  0.0  0.707107
1  0.282843  0.0  0.282843
2  0.176777  0.0  0.176777
```

I'd personally recommend the `numpy` solution because these data & analysis are better represented by a 3d array than a hierarchical DataFrame.

Comment: When I use the numpy approach, I get the same float error that I had in my original question, even when I try to to_numeric, errors='coerce' for the dataframe. The pandas solution was working but all of a sudden, it only returns two rows of the dataframe and I'm not even sure what it is calculating because the numbers do not match any of my original CV calculations. The only change I made was putting this pandas code into a tkinter GUI and it just stopped working when calculating CV between two points of two dataframes. Any advice?